# How to import nested json file into google sheets with some missing key:value pairs

Tags: json, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a nested json file which looks like this:

```
{
  "id - 1": {
    "name": "ABC",
    "date": "1995-12",
    "capital": "4045",
    "URL": "https://www.example.com/",
  },
  "id - 2": {
    "name": "BCD",
    "date": "1962-08",
    "capital": "1,500",
    "total members": "51",
    "parent": "XVY Company",
    "URL": "https://www.example.org/",
  },
  "id -3 ": {
        .
        .
        .

  }
}
```

I want to create a csv/speadsheet with the keys as titles. The problem is when there are some `key:value` pair missing in some ids which are present in others.

Eg: `parent` and `total_members` are not present in id-1, but are present in id-2.

In that case I would want an empty cell (or some null indicator) in the cell of the `id-1` spreadsheet.

```
name|date|capital|total-members| parent| url
ABC|1995-12|4045| null|null|https://www.example.com/
BCD|1962-08|1,500|51|XYZ company| https://www.example.org/
```

(I used `|` delimiter becuase the text contains `,`)

Is there any way other that manually identifying all fields and iterating through the json file in python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if it's the reply you want. Using jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), starting from

```
{
  "id - 1": {
    "name": "ABC",
    "date": "1995-12",
    "capital": "4045",
    "URL": "https://www.example.com/"
  },
  "id - 2": {
    "name": "BCD",
    "date": "1962-08",
    "capital": "1,500",
    "total members": "51",
    "parent": "XVY Company",
    "URL": "https://www.example.org/"
  }
}
```

and running

```
<input.json jq '.[]' | mlr --j2c unsparsify
```

you will have

```
name,date,capital,URL,total members,parent
ABC,1995-12,4045,https://www.example.com/,,
BCD,1962-08,"1,500",https://www.example.org/,51,XVY Company
```